# Apache common httpclient and httppost, how to make it block?

Tags: http, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-httpcomponents

I am using `httpclient` in `org.apache.httpcomponents` (version 4.5.2) for http post calls, the code I wrote:

```
HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
post.addHeader("content-type", "application/json");
StringEntity params = new StringEntity("param");
post.setEntity(params);
HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);

/***Other code section**/
cusmtomOtherFunction();
```

The problem is, I want to wait until the http post call has finished, then execute `cusmtomOtherFunction()`, how can I make this happen?

Comment: Pretty sure you have to do something with the response to cause it to block.  E.g. read the response data or get the status code

Comment: I have tried to get response status and print out the data, it doesn't work, any other suggestions?

Comment: Did you successfully get all the response data?  How could it not have blocked until completion if the data was available?  Can you try EntityUtils.consume(response.getEntity()) (without reading the data)

Comment: "System.out.println("Response Code : "
                    + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
            String line = "";
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }  " this is the code I added, I will try what you said

Comment: How do you know it didn't block? If you can see the data returned by the other web server then surely it blocked? You probably also want to close the reader.

Comment: yes, I can see the data printing on the other server while this server is going to the next function, I will close it and see if this helps